# .htaccess remove substring but keep query string , but substring with root exists

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have this issue I try to solve with .htaccess redirect.

a) I need to change links like this

```
domain/kniha/?download_file=1619&order=wc_order_57fd45906a1f4&email=zuzana.xyz%40gmail.com&key=0cdf331935ec8ccf184fd729fb922367
```

to this: (i.e. remove `kniha/` part and keep query string intact)

```
domain/?download_file=1619&order=wc_order_57fd45906a1f4&email=zuzana.xyz%40gmail.com&key=0cdf331935ec8ccf184fd729fb922367
```

But I have to keep intact request to `domain/kniha/` as this directory `/article` exists

So 
- if request is  `domain/kniha/` do nothing
- if request contains query string then change URL (remove substring for directory)

Note: it is for Wordpress site.

Can somebody helps me?

Thank you.
Richard

Comment: You want `kniha/` removed if there is **any** query string?

Comment: Yes, if there is any query string, remove "kniha/" . If there isn't query string, do nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^kniha / [L,R]
```

This will redirect the uri **/kniha** only when query string is present in the url.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It helped a lot. My final code is this: 
    <pre>  # change for /substring/

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/kniha

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .

RewriteRule ^kniha / [L,R] 

</IfModule>

# END redirect` </pre>